# How do I stop and reset a setInterval timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

How do I stop and reset this setInterval timer back to 00:00?

Setting `clearInterval(timer);` works for stopping the time but I can't figure out how to reset the time value back to 00:00.

Here's where I'm at:

**HTML**

```
<span class="timer">
  <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
const minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
const secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
let timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}

stopTimer = () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
};
```

I'm using this timer in a game so based on the users state I need to be able `start`, `stop`, and `restart` the time back to 0.

Comment: where is `totalSeconds` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening now is that your variable keeps going up, even when you "reset" the timer.

Simply add

```
totalSeconds = 0;
```

to your `stopTimer` function. This will reset the variable to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **totalSeconds** keeps track of your time.
The name of your function stopTimer() - maybe it should be restartTimer - seems a bit misleading since you're restarting the timer there but basically just set totalSeconds to 0 like:

```
stopTimer = () => {
  totalSeconds = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
};
```